# apache-poi-3.9 + creating Dropdown

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to create dropdown list in XLS using Apache-poi-3.9 .
Following code I have written ::

```
public class TestMacroTemplate {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
        DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint
                .createExplicitListConstraint(new String[] { "10", "20", "30" });
        DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList,
                dvConstraint);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
        sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("XLCellDropDown.xls");
        try {
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But it gives the following Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addValidationData(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidation;)V
    at ejb.TestMacroTemplate.main(TestMacroTemplate.java:31)
```

And the same code works with Apache-poi-3.2

Please help me.

Thanks ,
Nirav

Answer (score 3):

Apache POI have a [FAQ on this very problem](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). I'll quote from there, as it'll solve your problem

> **My code uses some new feature, compiles fine but fails when live with a "MethodNotFoundException", "NoSuchMethodError" or "IncompatibleClassChangeError"**
>
> You almost certainly have an older version of POI on your classpath. Quite a few runtimes and other packages will ship an older version of POI, so this is an easy problem to hit without your realising.
>
> The best way to identify the offending earlier jar file is with a few lines of java. These will load one of the core POI classes, and report where it came from.

```
ClassLoader classloader =
   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in `Apache poi 3.9` and i have tested it.just incluse these jars

```
poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
```